# Symfony Host Routing & AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, symfony, docker-compose, symfony5

I'm trying to setup a Symfony app that handles multiple bundles. Each bundle routes are registered as annotation type and is working without any issue/s on my docker local machine.

`config/services.yaml`

```
parameters:
  domain: '%env(DOMAIN)%'
```

`config/routes/annotations.yaml`

```
us_controllers:
  host: "app-us.{domain}"
  resource: '@AppUsBundle/Controller/'
  type: annotation
  defaults:
    domain: "%domain%"

ru_controllers:
  host: "app-ru.{domain}"
  resource: '@AppRuBundle/Controller/'
  type: annotation
  defaults:
    domain: "%domain%"

kernel:
  resource: ../../src/Kernel.php
  type: annotation
```

`src/UsBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\UsBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class DefaultController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/default', name: 'appus.index')]
    public function index(): Response
    {
        return $this->json(['message' => 'UsBundle']);
    }
}
```

`src/UsBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\RuBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class DefaultController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/default', name: 'appru.index')]
    public function index(): Response
    {
        return $this->json(['message' => 'RuBundle']);
    }
}
```

The issue is whenever I deploy the docker images to AWS ECS, I'm getting an HTTP 404 when trying to access either `app-us.{domain}` and `app-ru.domain`.

Using one controller resource entry in `config/routes/annotations.yaml`, I'm getting an HTTP 200 with `message: "UsBundle"`

```
controllers:
  resource: '@AppUsBundle/Controller/'
  type: annotation

kernel:
  resource: ../../src/Kernel.php
  type: annotation
```

Comment: What is the value of the `DOMAIN` environment variable when deploying to AWS?

Comment: @Jeroen van der Laan It's sample-staging.dev (That is the format value of DOMAIN env) when deployed to AWS

Comment: What if you bind the parameter `domain` and `die($domain)` in your controller?